# Disadvantages of using CGI scripts written in C for web server-side?

Tags: c, apache, cgi

I'm currently handling the simple server-side for an iPhone app using an Apache HTTP server with CGI scripts enabled and a CGI script written in C to handle requests, reading the HTTP query string and inserting/selecting from an SQLite database as required.

From what I've seen, this is a very uncommon setup, and most people write CGI scripts in Perl or something or don't use CGI scripts at all. I'd use something else just to be mainstream, but I knew CGI scripting in C well and didn't want to deal with something new at the time. And people have told me that using CGI scripts written in C is a bad idea, but when I ask why, they don't know. Why is it bad, given that I'm doing it for a small program?

Comment: CGI can be written in any language.  I've seen CGIs written in bash.

Comment: CGIs in bash were a prime target for the shellshock attack. Guess pure C would have been better there at least. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be just fine if it's a simple script without much tricky code. Some objections people might have are the following:

- **Security**: C doesn't have many built-in checks and balances compared to interpreted languages. What would cause the interpreter to throw an error in other languages could mean buffer overflows with data leakage or arbitrary code execution in C.
- **String handling**: This is often trickier and more error-prone in C compared to scripting languages (though on the other hand you don't get people trying to use regexes for everything regardless of how well-suited they are :P).
- **Development effort vs. payoff**: Many CGI scripts aren't performance critical, are mostly I/O bound such that optimizing CPU utilization doesn't get you much, or contain simple glue logic. Writing such scripts in a scripting language might be quicker.

Comment: OK, I understand why people would be against C for how strings and memory are handled. But those reasons alone aren't enough to dissuade me from using it for my small scripts; just have to be careful :)

Comment: Just watch those buffer sizes and off-by-ones. :)